# AngularJS ng-show after ajax request is ready

Tags: angularjs

I'm sending request and after I'll receive array I need to render answer. If array is empty I need to show one code, otherwise - athother code.

And now my template loads faster then request so shows part with "array is empty" condition. How to wait until request is finished?

```
// Template
<div ng-show="!!arr.length"> // I need to check this after request is finished.
   <div ng-repeat="(key, val) in arr">
      ...
   </div>
</div>
<div ng-show="!!arr.length" class="ng-hide"></div>
   Empty
</div>


// Controller
$scope.arr = [];
$http.get('url').then(function (response) {

  if(response) $scope.arr= response;
  // ng-show or ng-hide

});
```

Comment: You have the same expression on both `ng-show`. Change the expression on the second div or change from `ng-show=` to `ng-hide=`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Leave the `$scope.arr`variable to undefined, and only define it once you actually have received the array.

And then use this in your template:

```
<div ng-show="arr.length > 0">
    ...
</div>
<div ng-show="arr.length == 0"></div>
    Empty
</div>
```

Both conditions will be falsy if `arr` is undefined.

Of course, you could also introduce a boolean variable that is set to true once the response is available, if you find it clearer.

Or, probably the best solution, [configure your route](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider) to only switch to the page once the array is available, using its `resolve` configuration option.

Comment: it didn't work for me, first it will show the empty message,even there is some items in array, later it will show the array items.